# Move excerpt to always be directly below post content in admin

Tags: metabox

Sometimes, due to meta boxes added by plugins, the excerpt gets moved down the order in the admin page.

Is there a way I can force it to *always* be directly below the post content?

Here is the way I've tried:

```
function remove_wordpress_meta_boxes() {
   remove_meta_box( 'postexcerpt', 'page', 'normal' );
   add_meta_box('postexcerpt', __('Excerpt'), 'post_excerpt_meta_box', 'page', 'normal', 'high');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_wordpress_meta_boxes' );
```

`remove_meta_box()` works as expected, but re-adding the excerpt meta box doesn't seem to do anything to the ordering - I still have a plugin metabox appear above the excerpt.

Comment: Does it fix the problem for editing *pages*? If so, you need to repeat the code with `post` instead of `page`. If not, what's the plugin in question?

Comment: I've tried editing both posts and pages, changing the 2nd parameter so all combinations are tested. Nothing will budge Excerpt.  Initially I thought maybe plugin meta boxes were taking precedence, but when editing posts, I can see that even a core metabox (revisions) is appearing above excerpt. I could manually drag excerpt to its correct location, but I want to catch all method that will work for every user, every time.

Comment: Try the action `add_meta_boxes` instead of `admin_menu`

Comment: I would also advise clearing `meta-box-order_post` and `meta-box-order_page` in `wp_usermeta` for sanity - these will override any order defined in your code.

Comment: Thanks, @TheDeadMedic. Clearing both `meta-box-order_post` and `meta-box-order_page` did the trick and restored Excerpt to the top. I'd now like to prevent users from moving the Excerpt, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your code doesn't work is most likely that you've ordered your metaboxes before, and the that order has been saved into the `meta-box-order_page` meta value. This overrides the default setup.

Here's an example of the `meta-box-order_post` meta value:

```
a:3:{
     s:4:"side";    
         s:61:"submitdiv,formatdiv,categorydiv,tagsdiv-post_tag,postimagediv";
     s:6:"normal";  
         s:96:"revisionsdiv,postexcerpt,trackbacksdiv,postcustom,
               commentstatusdiv,commentsdiv,slugdiv,authordiv";
     s:8:"advanced";
         s:0:"";
}
```

Here I've just reformatted the serialized array for better readability.

### Sticky MetaBoxes:

To move a given metabox to the *top* position, for a given *context* and *post-type*, you can use this code snippet:

```
/**
 * Set some sticky metaboxes
 */

add_action( 'admin_init', function()
{
    if( function_exists( 'wpse_sticky_metabox' ) )
    {
         // Sticky metabox #1:
         wpse_sticky_metabox(
             array(
                 'cpt'      => 'page',
                 'context'  => 'normal',
                 'metabox'  => 'postexcerpt'
             )
         );

         // Sticky metabox #2:
         wpse_sticky_metabox(
             array(
                 'cpt'      => 'post',
                 'context'  => 'side',
                 'metabox'  => 'authordiv' 
             )
         );
    }
});
```

where you can adjust this to your needs.

Some info on the input parameters:

- `cpt` is the custom post type of the edit screen ( i.e. *post*, *page*, ...)
- `context` is the section where you want to make the metabox sticky. ( i.e. *normal*, *side*, *advanced*, ... )
- `metabox` is the *id* of the sticky meta-box ( i.e. *postexcerpt*, *authordiv*, ... )

### Sticky MetaBoxes - the plugin:

This is supported by the following demo plugin:

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: Sticky Meta-Boxes
 * Description: Set a given meta-box to the top, for a given cpt and context.
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/174980/26350
 * Author:      Birgir Erlendsson (birgire)
 * Version:     0.0.2
 */

function wpse_sticky_metabox( $args = array() )
{
    if( class_exists( 'MetaBoxSticker' ) )
    {
        $o = new MetaBoxSticker;
        $o->setup( $args )->activate();
    }
}

class MetaBoxSticker
{
    private $args;

    public function setup( $args = array() )
    {
        $default = array(
            'cpt'      => 'post',
            'context'  => 'normal',
            'metabox'  => 'postexcerpt'
        );
        $this->args = wp_parse_args( $args, $default );
        return $this;
    }

    public function activate()
    {
        add_filter(
            sprintf(
                'get_user_option_meta-box-order_%s',
                $this->args['cpt']
            ),
            array( $this, 'filter' ),
            PHP_INT_MAX
        );

        add_action( 
            'add_meta_boxes', 
            array( $this, 'relocate' ), 
            PHP_INT_MAX 
        );
    }

    public function relocate()
    {
        //-----------------------
        // Get the user input:
        //-----------------------
        $_cpt      = sanitize_key( $this->args['cpt']     );
        $_metabox  = sanitize_key( $this->args['metabox'] );
        $_context  = sanitize_key( $this->args['context'] );

        //-----------------------
        // Relocate 'high' metaboxes to 'default' in the current context
        //-----------------------                  
        global $wp_meta_boxes;
        if( isset( $wp_meta_boxes[$_cpt][$_context]['high'] ) )
        {                                                           
            foreach( $wp_meta_boxes[$_cpt][$_context]['high'] as $id => $item )
            {
                if( isset( $item['callback'] ) )
                {
                    remove_meta_box( 
                        $id, 
                        $_cpt, 
                        $_context 
                    );

                    add_meta_box( 
                        $id, 
                        $item['title'], 
                        $item['callback'], 
                        $_cpt, 
                        $_context, 
                        'default', 
                        $item['args'] 
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function filter( $order )
    {
        //-----------------------
        // Get the user input:
        //-----------------------                               
        $_cpt      = sanitize_key( $this->args['cpt']     );
        $_metabox  = sanitize_key( $this->args['metabox'] );
        $_context  = sanitize_key( $this->args['context'] );

        //-----------------------
        // Handle the case if the current user hasn't made any meta-box ordering before:
        //-----------------------
        if( empty( $order ) )
        {
            global $wp_meta_boxes;
            if( ! isset( $wp_meta_boxes[$_cpt][$_context] ) )
               return $order;

            $order = array();
            foreach( $wp_meta_boxes[$_cpt] as $context_key => $context_item )
            {
                $tmp = array();
                foreach( $context_item as $priority_key => $priority_item )
                {
                    foreach( $priority_item as $metabox_key => $metabox_item )
                    {
                        $tmp[] = $metabox_key;
                    }
                }
                $order[$context_key] = join( ',', $tmp );
            }
        }

        //-----------------------
        // Let's make sure the context exists:
        //-----------------------
        if( ! isset( $order[$_context] ) )
            return $order;

        //-----------------------
        // Remove the given meta-box from the whole order array:
        //-----------------------
        foreach( $order as $context_key => $string )
        {
            $tmp = explode( ',', $string );
            $key = array_search( $_metabox, $tmp );
            if( ! empty( $key ) )
            {
                unset( $tmp[$key] );
                $order[$context_key] = join( ',', $tmp );
            }
        }

        //-----------------------
        // Make the given meta-box sticky for a given context
        //-----------------------
        $tmp = explode( ',', $order[$_context] );
        array_unshift( $tmp, $_metabox );
        $order[$_context] = join( ',', $tmp );

        return $order;
    }

} // end class
```

This plugin should also work, even if you haven't made any ordering before.

It also respects the *Screen Options*, i.e. wether a meta-box is visible or not.

I hope you can extend this further to your needs.

Comment: You've left out the `array( $this, 'filter' ),` arg to `add_filter()` in `activate()` - great stuff though!

Comment: Thanks @bonger, hopefully I've inserted the whole code now ;-)

Comment: Thank you, @birgire for such a detailed answer. I've activated your plugin and added your sample code (just Sticky metabox #2) then tested on a post. It does indeed move the Excerpt above core WP meta boxes e.g. 'Revisions', so that's great :) However, a theme meta box and a plugin meta box (Attachments by Jonathan Christopher) still appear above the Excerpt. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, I just tested it with the Attachments plugin ([this usage example](https://github.com/jchristopher/attachments/blob/master/docs/usage.md)) and `wpse_sticky_metabox( array( 'cpt' => 'post', 'context' => 'normal', 'metabox' => 'postexcerpt' ) );` and it works as expected on my WP install. I always get the *excerpt* meta-box on top.

Comment: With @TheDeadMedic's guidance, I've cleared out `meta-box-order_post` and `meta-box-order_page` which has restored Excerpt to the top of the admin page.  A nice addition to your plugin would be to make it impossible for the sticky post to be moved by the user :)

Comment: That's strange, because no matter how I order the metaboxes, the sticky ones are always on top. The plugin should take that in account too.

Comment: Hopefully now I've cleared out all ordering settings, and forced excerpt to the top, everything will be great.  I've added the following to prevent excerpt from being moved: http://pastebin.com/a8zueCi5

Comment: aha, I think I found one use-case around the ordering of the plugin: If you have already ordered your meta-boxes, and then add a new meta-box, with the `high` priority, then it will be ordered above the sorted ones. That's because WordPress uses the following priority-ordering in that case: `high, sorted, core, default, low`. So I guess if we could add the new meta-box into the pre-existing ordering array, then this case would be solved.

Comment: I updated the plugin with a workaround for the case I described [here above](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174934/move-excerpt-to-always-be-directly-below-post-content-in-admin#comment254833_174980).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, you can only change the default ordering, if a user has modified it there's not a huge amount you can do without writing a reset script.

Either way, here's how you change the default order properly, (disclaimer, I wrote the article) https://ozthegreat.io/wordpress/wordpress-how-to-move-the-excerpt-meta-box-above-the-editor/

```
/**
 * Removes the regular excerpt box. We're not getting rid
 * of it, we're just moving it above the wysiwyg editor
 *
 * @return null
 */
function oz_remove_normal_excerpt() {
    remove_meta_box( 'postexcerpt' , 'post' , 'normal' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'oz_remove_normal_excerpt' );

/**
 * Add the excerpt meta box back in with a custom screen location
 *
 * @param  string $post_type
 * @return null
 */
function oz_add_excerpt_meta_box( $post_type ) {
    if ( in_array( $post_type, array( 'post', 'page' ) ) ) {
        add_meta_box(
            'oz_postexcerpt',
            __( 'Excerpt', 'thetab-theme' ),
            'post_excerpt_meta_box',
            $post_type,
            'after_title',
            'high'
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'oz_add_excerpt_meta_box' );

/**
 * You can't actually add meta boxes after the title by default in WP so
 * we're being cheeky. We've registered our own meta box position
 * `after_title` onto which we've regiestered our new meta boxes and
 * are now calling them in the `edit_form_after_title` hook which is run
 * after the post tile box is displayed.
 *
 * @return null
 */
function oz_run_after_title_meta_boxes() {
    global $post, $wp_meta_boxes;
    # Output the `below_title` meta boxes:
    do_meta_boxes( get_current_screen(), 'after_title', $post );
}
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'oz_run_after_title_meta_boxes' );
```

Comment: Please post the content from your article in your answer. If your site goes offline, this answer will mean nothing to others :-)

Comment: Of course, will do now!