# Make metabox always be on top (sticky)

Tags: metabox

i want to make some metaboxes (my own and some default) to be always on top.

not matter if new meta boxes with high property will be added (from plugins for example).

i try to use [this solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174934/move-excerpt-to-always-be-directly-below-post-content-in-admin) but seems it can't put all the metxboxs i need over the "high property"

any possible solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: I updated the [plugin (v 0.0.2)](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/174980/26350) in my answer, to handle the case when a new metabox, with the `'high'` priority, is added after we have already sorted our metaboxes - the metaboxes with the `'high'` priority are always above the `'sorted'` ones.

Comment: @birgire one bug, if i want to make metabox sticky on all pages (posts, pages, custom post type etc...) so i set "cpt" to NULL this not working.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working. The *"on all custom post types"* feature is not (yet?) implemented, but you might consider looping through [`get_post_types()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types). I've some ideas how to simplify the plugin, but that will have to wait ;-)

Comment: Thanks @birgire i will be glad to know when the update version will be ready.